# Геолокации в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, геолокация

Такой код взял из w3schools.Я копировал и создал файл index.html в XAMPP/Wamp Server запустил не работает геолокация домен есть там тоже не сработало в чем проблема?Ошибки не выдает просто напросто не работает браузер яндекс.На самом w3schools работает а так нет

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");

        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else { 
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
            "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так проверьте с помощью консоли

Comment: Тут пишет не работает на HTTP нужен HTTPS а для HTTP как получить координаты?(геолокация)

Comment: Без https это будет костыль, который займет много времени(и соответственно денег). Лучше купите сертификат и поставьте его(а если пользуетесь хостингом - всё ещё проще, просто платите). Протолок http - не особо безопасен, так что это разумная мера предосторожности браузера.

Comment: Понятно.. спасибо вам блогадарю

Comment: @Klimenkomud оформите как ответ.

Comment: @AGS17 Оформил как ответ, но это скорее получился не ответ на заданный вопрос, а рекомендация, каким путём нужно идти

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Протокол `http` - небезопасен, так что это разумная мера предосторожности браузера по ограничении получения геолокации.

Без `https` это будет костыль, который займет много времени (и соответственно денег). Лучше купите сертификат и поставьте его (а если пользуетесь хостингом - всё ещё проще, просто платите).

P.S. Для `https` требуется `SSL` сертификат, такой предоставляют практически все более-менее крупные хостинг-провайдеры.